# Android widget scrolling

Tags: android, widget, scroll

I am looking for a sollution to implement scrolling in an Android home screen widget.
I've implemented it with a List control already, but it only works for Android versions 3.0+, otherwise (2.3.7 for example) it says that a list control is not allowed for app widgets.

However I already saw a scrolling widget, running on a 2.3.7 device. Any ideas how to do that?

thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".WidgetName"
              android:label="@string/WidgetLabel">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/widgetresource"/>

        <!--this is the part that you will need to add-->
        <meta-data android:name="LauncherMetadata.Requirements.Scrollable"
                   android:value="true" />
</receiver>
```

Some launchers support scrolling on 2.3 and lower, some do not. This will allow the launchers that support it to use your widget. Launches which do not support scrolling will not show the widget as an option.